# Loop associated of array using JavaScript to HTML (JSON)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I am wondering when I loop the assoc array in my html file return only first value not all assoc array, but when I view it in console.log its working correctly but when I print it in HTML **no error** but not all data will loop. 
**How to process print completely LOOP all the data from associated of array to html using** *javaScript.*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="mypanel"></p>

<script>
var dataRequest = [
  {
    "place": "Visaya",
    "countryCode": "PH",
    "region": "Calabarzon",
    "latitude": "14.5666700",
    "longitude": "121.0333300",
    "distanceMiles": 0.37,
    "distanceKilometers": 0.59,
    "directionAngle": 27.84,
    "directionHeading": "NNE"
  },
  {
    "place": "Tejeros",
    "countryCode": "PH",
    "region": "Calabarzon",
    "latitude": "14.5666700",
    "longitude": "121.0333300",
    "distanceMiles": 0.37,
    "distanceKilometers": 0.59,
    "directionAngle": 27.84,
    "directionHeading": "NNE"
  },
  {
    "place": "Bancal",
    "countryCode": "PH",
    "region": "Calabarzon",
    "latitude": "14.5666700",
    "longitude": "121.0333300",
    "distanceMiles": 0.37,
    "distanceKilometers": 0.59,
    "directionAngle": 27.84,
    "directionHeading": "NNE"
  }
];

dataRequest.forEach(function(value, index) {
        
   var text = ` Place                : ${value.place} <br />
                 val1                : ${value.countryCode} <br />
                 val2                : ${value.region} <br />
                 val3                : ${value.latitude} <br />
                 val4                : ${value.longitude} <br /> 
                 val5                : ${value.distanceMiles} <br />
                 val6                : ${value.distanceKilometers} <br />  
                 val7                : ${value.directionAngle} <br />
                 val8                : ${value.directionHeading} <br />`;
   
   // place to my HTML but not looping all data why??              
   document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = text;
   
   // with console all dataRequest will loop
   console.log(text);

});

</body>
</html>
```

Here' image that result for that script: 
**Result:** https://www.screencast.com/t/1F7zyUcxkd 
**Expected:** https://www.screencast.com/t/1F7zyUcxkd

I need javaScript version for looping data in HTML
Thanks in advance for helping me..

Comment: You're overwriting the same element each time through the loop. You'll only see the final value. If you want to see all of them, you should concatenate rather than overwriting.

Comment: });
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Barmar can you give me more details and idea exactly what you mean, I am not really got yet in javaScript. Thanks

Comment: Someone already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for information seek. It will be better to not update the inner HTML so many times. you can do this instead.

```js
document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = dataRequest.map(value => {
   return     ` Place                : ${value.place} <br />
                 val1                : ${value.countryCode} <br />
                 val2                : ${value.region} <br />
                 val3                : ${value.latitude} <br />
                 val4                : ${value.longitude} <br /> 
                 val5                : ${value.distanceMiles} <br />
                 val6                : ${value.distanceKilometers} <br />  
                 val7                : ${value.directionAngle} <br />
                 val8                : ${value.directionHeading} <br />`;
   }).join("");
```

Comment: Thanks  Sir. @D. Seah, great, no repeat html many times perfect! Thank you very much..

Comment: Hello Sir @D. Sean
...
How can I make input field unique using the function below inter 0 <=5 or anways
... PART 1

document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = dataRequest.map(value => {

  var text = "";
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

   return  ` 
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="gpsPlace_nb" name="gpsPlaceNb-${i}" value="${value.geoplugin_place}" class="form-control">
             </div>

Comment: ... PART 2
<div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" id="gpsCountryCode_nb" name="gpsCountryCodeNb-${i}" value="${value.geoplugin_countryCode}" class="form-control">
             </div>
   
           `;
   }

}).join("");

Comment: it is hard to understand your questions. Can you please post a new question? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because everytime you are updating the innerHTML with the new text here,

```
document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML = text;
```

You can do the following,

```
document.getElementById("mypanel").innerHTML += text;
```

Comment: If that solves your problem please mark this as your answer. @RennielFernandez